# Disable past dates and 2 weeks from now in JCalendar

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I want to disable past dates and 2 weeks from now from a `JCalendar`.

I already have this code:

```
jDateChooser1.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(new Date());
((JTextFieldDateEditor)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor()).setEditable(false);
```

I already can disable past dates but how about disabling future dates like 2 weeks from now?

Comment: Which Date API are you using ? Is it JAVA date API ?

Comment: It is JCalendar API  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25501373/230513), you can use an `IDateEvaluator` like `MinMaxDateEvaluator` to invalidate a range of dates:

```
private static class RangeEvaluator extends MinMaxDateEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        return !super.isInvalid(date);
    }
}
```

Then you can specify a range of invalid dates, e.g. a day before and two weeks after:

```
    Calendar min = Calendar.getInstance();
    min.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
    max.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);
    RangeEvaluator re = new RangeEvaluator();
    re.setMinSelectableDate(min.getTime());
    re.setMaxSelectableDate(max.getTime());
    JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();
    jc.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(re);
    jc.setCalendar(jc.getCalendar());
```

Note that you can add multiple instances of `RangeEvaluator` to handle different ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but I imagine using a date in the future would do this:

```
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + 14 * 86400 * 1000); -- set the date 14 days forward
jDateChooser1.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(d);
((JTextFieldDateEditor)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor()).setEditable(false);
```

Instead of working with a Date object and having to use setTime(milliseconds) you might want to use a proper Calendar object which has better methods for altering the date and so on.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 14);
Date twoweeks = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

I already have answered my own question by the help of trashgod's code.

Here:

```
Calendar min = Calendar.getInstance();
min.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
max.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2000000);
RangeEvaluator re = new RangeEvaluator();
re.setMinSelectableDate(min.getTime());
re.setMaxSelectableDate(max.getTime());
// JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();


 jDateChooser1.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(min.getTime());
 jDateChooser1.getJCalendar().setMaxSelectableDate(max.getTime());
((JTextFieldDateEditor)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor()).setEditable(false);
```

Thanks! :D